# How to apply loop in two files in awk with one matched column?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to extract data from two files with a common column but I am unable to fetch the required data.

```
File1
A   B   C   D   E  F  G
Dec 3  abc  10 2B 21  OK
Dec 1  %xyZ 09 3F 09 NOK
Dec 5  mnp  89 R5 11  OK

File2

 H   I
abc 10
xyz 00
pqr 45
```

I am able to get output A B C D E F G but unable to add I in between C & E column.

```
Trail 1:

awk 'FNR==1{next}
 NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}
 {k=$3; sub(/^\%/,"",k)} k in a{print $1,$2,$3,$4,a[$2],$5,$6,$7; delete a[k]}
  END{for(k in a) print k,a[k] > "unmatched"}' File2 File1 > matched
```

Required output:

```
matched: 
A   B   C   D  I  E  F  G
Dec 3  abc  10 10 2B 21  OK
Dec 1  %xyZ 09 00 3F 09 NOK
unmatched : 
 H  I
pqr 45

Could you please help me for getting this output please ? Thank you.
```

Comment: Instead of `print $1,$2,$3,$4,a[$2] ...`, don't you want `... a[k] ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful that you have an upper case Z in file1. I put it to lower case in my test --- if it's not a typo it's another small detail to deal with.

```
 $ awk 'FNR==1 {next}
        NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}
        {k=$3; sub(/^\%/,"",k)}
        k in a {print $1,$2,$3,$4,a[k],$5,$6,$7; delete a[k]}
        END {for(k in a) print k,a[k] > "unmatched"}' File2 File1 > matched

$ cat matched
Dec 3 abc 10 10 2B 21 OK
Dec 1 %xyz 09 00 3F 09 NOK

$ cat unmatched
pqr 45
```

---

**File 2 with four columns**:

```
$ cat a
A   B   C   D   E  F  G
Dec 3  abc  10 2B 21  OK
Dec 1  %xyz 09 3F 09 NOK
Dec 5  mnp  89 R5 11  OK

$ cat b
 H   I  J   K
abc 10  j1 k1
xyz 00  j2 k2
pqr 45  j3 k3

$ cat x.awk
FNR==1 {next}
NR==FNR {a[$1]=$0; next}
{k=$3; sub(/^\%/,"",k)}
k in a {
    split(a[k], b)
    print $1,$2,b[2],$3,b[3],b[4],$4,$5,$6,$7; delete a[k]
}
END {for(k in a) print a[k] > "unmatched"}

$ awk -f x.awk b a
Dec 3 10 abc j1 k1 10 2B 21 OK
Dec 1 00 %xyz j2 k2 09 3F 09 NOK

$ cat unmatched 
pqr 45  j3 k3
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it and yes it is a typo

Comment: Can I ask you one question?. If my FILE2 contains 4 columns(H,I,J,K) and I want the output in the sequence  A B I C J K  D E F G
and I wrote a{print $1,$2,$a[$2,$1,$3,$4],$4,$5,$6,$7; delete a[k]} and it is not working, could you please suggest sir ?

Comment: See edit for updated version with four columns in the second file. Take a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html --- if you work through that up through the chapter on arrays you'll soon be the one answering awk questions on SO :-)